# How to have a function return a variable that can be used in the rest of the program? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a name generator function which will then return the parts of the name for use in the rest of my program. I put this inside of a function so that I could give the user the option to regenerate the name, instead of being stuck with the first one.

Putting the lists inside the function, and then being able to call the function again causes the random numbers to recalculate, so a new name is generated, but when I try to use "return" to move the variables outside of the function, I get an error.

There's probably a better way to do this, but I'm drawing a blank.

Here's what I have:

```
def naming():
    titles = ["Sir", "Dr.", "Reverend", "Madam", "Master", 'Miss', 'Mrs.']
    descriptors = ['sane', 'feelbe', 'cross-eyed', 'bow-legged', 'mad man', 'strange', 'frail', 'old', 'insane', 'cruel', 'bonkers', 'big-headed', 'knock-kneed', 'esquire', 'the huge']

    name = input("What is your name?\n> ")

    title = titles[random.randrange(0, 6)]
    descriptor = descriptors[random.randrange(0,14)]

    print(f"You shall be called {title} {name} the {descriptor}")
    print("Does that work for you?")
    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "yes":
        return title, name, descriptor
    if choice == "no":
        print("Sorry, I'll try again.")
        naming()
    else:
        print("Sorry I don't understand.")
        naming()
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out on my own. Here's what I did:

```
while True:
    titles = ["Sir", "Dr.", "Reverend", "Madam", "Master", 'Miss', 'Mrs.']
    descriptors = ['sane', 'feelbe', 'cross-eyed', 'bow-legged', 'mad man', 'strange', 'frail', 'old', 'insane', 'cruel', 'bonkers', 'big-headed', 'knock-kneed', 'scissor-handed', 'huge']

    name = input("What is your name?\n> ")

    title = titles[random.randrange(0, 6)]
    descriptor = descriptors[random.randrange(0,14)]

    print(f"You shall be called {title} {name} the {descriptor}")
    print("Does that work for you?")
    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "yes":
        break
    if choice == "no":
        print("Sorry, I'll try again.")
    else:
        print("Sorry I don't understand.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, have you tried to atribute the return values to variables?

IE:

```py
title, name, descriptor = naming()
```